# I need to create a plot with two seperate boxplots with grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

As in the title, i know it may be confusing so i am showing what i want to be the end result.

[image: My plot]

My data looks like that:

```
male female number
7    6      one
5    3      one
4    1      four
7    4      three
5    5      two
3    5      three
1    2      one
...
```

I tried this

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=male,fill=number))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=P_3_2,fill=number))
```

But this doesn't seem to work and i can't seperate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working?

```
library(data.table)
a = melt(data)

ggplot(a, aes(x = variable,y=value,fill = number))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: It works indeed. Thank you very much. I just needed to convert the data which was list to data.table

Answer (score 0):

For a ggplot-style solution, it is usually more convenient to pivot your two `x` variables into one column in the beginning, which is

```
data %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
```

Then you can either use a [grouped boxplot](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html) or a facet that split among variables.